# Fullcalendar external drag & drop does not work correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, fullcalendar, jquery-ui-draggable, fullcalendar-3

I am trying to implement a Fullcalendar functionality like so: an external event is dragged to the calendar, then the event is saved to the database via ajax, with its title, start and end dates. 
I did achieve making the event title and start date/time to be saved to the DB, however I cannot fix the following couple of issues:

1. Currently, the `end` date/time saved to the DB is the same as the `start` date/time.

   - How do I make the end date to be 24h after the start date for all day events?
   - How do I get the exact `start` and `end` dates for a fixed duration event?
2. Once the event is dragged and saved to the DB, I cannot drag-drop any more events until I hit F5

My HML is the following:

```
<div id='external-events'>
   <div class="fc-events-container">
      <div>All Day Events</div>
      <div class='fc-event' data-color='#28A745'>All Day Event</div>
      <div>Fixed Duration Events</div>
      <div class='fc-event' data-color='#50C1E9'>Event From 8am till 5 pm</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
$('#external-drag').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    editable: true,
    droppable: true,
    defaultDate: new Date(),
    selectable: true,
    events: "../../ajax/get_events.php",

    drop: function( date, allDay, jsEvent, ui ) {
        var start =  date.format();
        var end =  date.format();
        var title = $.trim($(this).text()); 
            $.ajax({
                url: '../../ajax/add_event.php',
                data: 'title='+ title+'&start='+ start +'&end='+ end,
                type: "POST",
                success: function(json) {
                    alert('Added Successfully');
                },
                error: function() {
                    alert('Error');
                }
            });
            calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent',
            {
                title: title,
                start: start,
                end: end,
                allDay: allDay
            },
            true
        );
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, some background context to what you're experiencing: although you've labelled your second event as "from 8 to 5pm", that has no actual practical effect. If you drop **either** of your draggable items onto a time-aware calendar view (e.g. week view) then it will gain a start date and time. On a view such as month, which has no concept of specific times of day, then it will just gain a start date, without a time attached.

However in both cases, there is no end date. Once you add the event to the calendar via [renderEvent](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/renderEvent), then fullCalendar will assign it a default duration (as per the 
 [defaultAllDayEventDuration](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/defaultAllDayEventDuration) or [defaultTimedEventDuration](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/defaultTimedEventDuration) settings, as appropriate). You can use that to work out the notional end date (although the event object doesn't actually have its `end` property set unless you set [forceEventDuration](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/forceEventDuration) to `true`).

---

Now to a solution:

If you want to control it so that specific dragged items have pre-defined times, you would have to specify the time data in the `data-` properties of the relevant draggable items. Then you need to get those values in your `drop` callback, the same way as you do with the title, and use them when creating your event.

It took a bit of fiddling to get to this point, especially with the moment objects, but it now appears to do what you want - as far as I understand it.

```
drop: function(date, jsEvent, ui) {
  var element = $(this);
  var title = $.trim(element.text());
  var color = element.data("color");
  var start = moment(date.format()); //lose the extended fullCalendar moment with its "ambiguously-timed" feature, which gets in the way here
  var end = start.clone();
  var allDay = true;
  console.log(start.format(), end.format());
  if (typeof element.data("starttime") !== 'undefined') {
    //timed events
    var starttime = moment.duration(element.data("starttime"));
    var endtime = moment.duration(element.data("endtime"));
    start.set({ "hour": starttime.hours(), "minute": starttime.minutes()});
    end.set({ "hour": endtime.hours(), "minute": endtime.minutes()});
    allDay = false;
    console.log(starttime.hours());
  } else {
    //allday events
    end.add({ days: 1 });
  }
  console.log("title=" + title + "&start=" + start.format() + "&end=" + end.format());
  $.ajax({
            url: '../../ajax/add_event.php',
            data: 'title='+ title+'&start='+ start.format() +'&end='+ end.format(),
            type: "POST",
            success: function(json) {
                alert('Added Successfully');
            },
            error: function() {
                alert('Error');
            }
        });
  calendar.fullCalendar(
    "renderEvent",
    {
      title: title,
      start: start,
      end: end,
      color: color,
      allDay: allDay
    },
    true
  );
}
```

Demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/GRRXwRL?editors=1010

N.B. Note that if a user drags an event onto a time-aware view like the week view, it will still create the events exactly as per the settings in the draggable, and will ignore whatever time of day they dropped it on. It's possible this could be confusing or irritating to some users - but I guess it depends what you're trying to achieve exactly.

P.S. I don't know where you got the idea that the `drop` callback has an `allDay` parameter. It's clearly not there in the [documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/drop). You can't use that, so I've removed it in my version.